# Diagonalize a dot product with Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

How can I diagonalize the following operator?

$$\lambda \hat{\vec{\sigma}}\cdot\vec{r}$$

where $\lambda$ is a real constant, $\hat{\vec{\sigma}}=(\hat{\sigma_{x}},\hat{\sigma_{y}},\hat{\sigma_{z}}) $ is the Pauli operator and $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ is the position operator.

Comment: Do you mean diagonalize the 2x2 matrix ? A priori, the Pauli matrices and the position operator do not act on the same space, so you should be able to diagonalize both simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, and then is the autovalue the product of the two different autovalues of position and spin-operator? For example: $$\hat{\sigma_{x}}\cdot x$$ has autovalue $$\mp 1\times x$$ ? @Adam

Comment: what does $\mp 1$ mean?

Comment: 1 and -1 are the two possible autovalues of the $\sigma_{x}$ operator

Comment: @CosmicVane: why don't you do the same thing for your case. You just need to diagonalize a 2x2 matrix, that should be pretty simple...

Comment: @CosmicVane: another way to find the result is to to define $\hat \sigma_r$, such that $\hat{\vec{\sigma}}.\vec{r}=\hat\sigma_r r$. $\hat \sigma_r$ is just a rotation of $\hat{\vec{\sigma}}$ and has the same eigenvalues than the other Pauli matrices.

Comment: You can use some notes I wrote for advanced high school or undergraduates to work through this problem yourself. A pdf version of the notes is here: http://public.lanl.gov/mparis/qmp.pdf -- And the relevant section with exercise problems start on page 32, section 5 of chapter 2.

Answer (score 3):

This operator commutes with $\vec{p} = (p_x,p_y,p_z)$ (an arbitrary vector operator in orbital space) so lets use as basis $|\vec{p} , \pm  \rangle $, with $\pm$ being the spin eigenvalue. The matrix in this basis takes the form:

$
\lambda \left ( \begin{matrix}
p_{z} & p_{-}\\ 
p_{+} & -p_{z}
\end{matrix} \right )
$

With $p_{+} = p_x+ip_y, p_{-}=p_{+}^{*}$. The determinant is $-\lambda^2p^2$ and the trace $0$, giving us eigenvalues of $\pm \lambda p$. Knowing this, lets translate our vector $\vec{p}$ to spherical coordinates:

$\lambda p\left ( \begin{matrix}
\cos\theta_{p} & \sin\theta_{p}\mathrm{e}^{-i\phi_{p}}\\ 
\sin\theta_{p}\mathrm{e}^{i\phi_{p}} & -\cos\theta_{p}
\end{matrix} \right )$

Diagonalization and vectors proceed as usual for a matrix in this form.

$|\vec{p} , +\lambda p  \rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}} |\vec{p} , +  \rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\phi}{2}} |\vec{p} , -  \rangle $
$|\vec{p} , -\lambda p  \rangle = -\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}} |\vec{p} , +  \rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\phi}{2}} |\vec{p} , -  \rangle $